# Accessing private from static method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, static-methods

Why this works? I mean, accessing the private variable.

```
class Test {
    private $q = 0;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->q = 1;
    }
    public static function EpicConstruct() {
        $test = new self();
        $test->q = 2;
        return $test;
    }
}

$test = Test::EpicConstruct();
```

Comment: Because you're accessing it from the same class.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Think about it like a men's and women's locker room. Objects of the same class can see each other's privates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are accessing the member in the correct context, namely: the class that defines the private member.

Comment: So i can work with any object of this class this way? I think i understand how decorator pattern works now. Thanks!

Comment: @smsteel As long as it is the same class: yes. With the decorator pattern, not so much: as a decorator is a class that either extends the class, or, more typically, extends/implements a common supertype (some base class or interface). The former kind of decorator will only have access to members that are at least `protected`, the latter only to `public` members of the class (or `protected` members of the supertype).